# Git add Folder with Existing Git Repository

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, repository, git-add

I am making a git repository for my MacVim installation. Some of the plugins in my repository have their own .git folders and repo.   The problem is...  when I try to add one of these folders to my main repository, it does nothing.

My guess:

I can't add the folder because it is a git repo on it's own.  I must add as a submodule or remove the .git folder.

How do I add my sub repos as a submodule?

```
bryan-mini:.vim bsaltzman$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit: 
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   bundle/YouCompleteMe (modified content)
#   modified:   bundle/nerdtree (modified content)
#   modified:   bundle/ultisnips (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")   

// This 
bryan-mini:.vim bsaltzman$ git add bundle/YouCompleteMe/
//  OR THIS
bryan-mini:.vim bsaltzman$ git submodule add bundle/YouCompleteMe/
repo URL: 'bundle/YouCompleteMe/' must be absolute or begin with ./|../

bryan-mini:.vim bsaltzman$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   bundle/YouCompleteMe (modified content)
#   modified:   bundle/nerdtree (modified content)
#   modified:   bundle/ultisnips (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you might have correctly added those repos as submodules but you've changed/added/deleted a file inside those repos. If you cd into bundle/nerdtree and do a 'git status' it should tell you what is different. If you get the submodule back into a clean state the top-level one should stop saying "modified content"

Also, your command:

```
git submodule add bundle/YouCompleteMe/
```

is incorrect. 'git submodule add' takes a repo url like so:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
```

But from your output it looks like you've already done that correctly at some point. You appear to be using Pathogen to manage your submodules - the docs for it should walk you through this process pretty well. Or you could switch to Vundle which apparently has some advantages (personally I'm still on Pathogen).

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to add repos existing in sub-folders is simple execute:

`git submodule add (repo url)` in parent folder.

For example:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git submodule add https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
```